# Cannot align images in same row with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and now making a website with it. 
I want to align small images in one row for my mobile view. The code is used for it is below

```
<div class="mobile">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                <a href="shop"><img src="assets/img/icon/birthday.png" alt="" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"><p style="text-transform: uppercase;"><b>Birthday</b></p></a>
            </div>   
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                <a href="shop"><img src="assets/img/icon/birthday.png" alt="" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"><p style="text-transform: uppercase;"><b>Birthday</b></p></a>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this, the result is below

[Not in one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVHsN.png)

All I want is that it appear side to side and not stacked. Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you use bootstrap 4

Comment: yes its the latest version

Answer (score 0):

`col-sm-1` is too small and the width doesn't fit the content that the reason it broke line.

**so  set `col-sm->1`**

Also in bootstrap 4 there is no `xs` size. so remove it

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <a href="shop"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg" alt="" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"><p style="text-transform: uppercase;"><b>Birthday</b></p></a>
            </div>   
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <a href="shop"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg" alt="" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"><p style="text-transform: uppercase;"><b>Birthday</b></p></a>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its still the same result for me :(

Comment: Bootstrap v4.0.0

Comment: look at your bootstrap links and scripts in the head tag (you can copy main) because it looks like bootstrap does not load

Comment: Its just a small part I am trying to work on, bootstrap is definitely working because the whole website is full of Bootstrap buttons and other elements

Comment: look at you F12 maybe some style override your defention(also try to refresh cache)